# how to combine multiple models into one viewmodel based on a condition ? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have the following three models:

```
namespace Company.Model {
    class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

    } }
```

and

```
namespace Company.Model
{
    class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeDOB { get; set; }
        public char? EmployeeGender { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeEmailID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeJoiningDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeConfirmationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeExpectedInTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmployeeExpectedOutTime { get; set; }
        public bool? EmployeeIsResigned { get; set; }
        public double? EmployeeSalary { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeDesignation { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Company.Model
{
    class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I need to combine all three into one viewmodel, based on the condition that Employee.CountryId=Country.CountrId and Employee.DepartmentId=Department.DepartmentId.

I basically want a join on the tables, so as to get country name and department name of each employee.

Comment: You can use `linq`.

Comment: can you please give an example? im new to this

Comment: If you are new to this, then look at a tutorial and come back with a specific code problem.